# Rails: How to listen to / pull from service or queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, apache-kafka, microservices

Most Rails applications work in a way that they are waiting for requests comming from a client and then do their magic.
But if I want to use a Rails application as part of a microservice architecture (for example) with some asychonious communication (Serivce A sends an event into a Kafka or RabbitMQ queue and Service B - my Rails app - is supposed to listen to this queue), how can I tune/start the Rails app to immediately listen to a queue and being triggered by event from there? (Meaning the initial trigger is not comming from a client, but from the App itself.)

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: rails is a web framework. That's what it does, handle web requests. If you need to monitor job/event queue (kafka or whatever), you'll need to use something else.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev what would you recommend - just a manual Ruby script, or some other Ruby framework, which is useful for this case or maybe other language altogether?

Comment: awesome reply @SergioTulentsev way to add absolutely no value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just set up RabbitMQ messaging within my application and will be implementing for decoupled (multiple, distributed) applications in the next day or so. I found [this](http://codetunes.com/2014/event-sourcing-on-rails-with-rabbitmq/) article very helpful (and the [RabbitMQ tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html), too). All the code below is for RabbitMQ and assumes you have a RabbitMQ server up and running on your local machine.

Here's what I have so far - that's working for me:

```
  #Gemfile
  gem 'bunny'
  gem 'sneakers'
```

I have a `Publisher` that sends to the queue:

```
  # app/agents/messaging/publisher.rb
  module Messaging
    class Publisher
      class << self

        def publish(args)
          connection = Bunny.new
          connection.start
          channel = connection.create_channel
          queue_name = "#{args.keys.first.to_s.pluralize}_queue"
          queue = channel.queue(queue_name, durable: true)
          channel.default_exchange.publish(args[args.keys.first].to_json, :routing_key => queue.name)
          puts "in #{self}.#{__method__}, [x] Sent #{args}!"
          connection.close
        end

      end
    end
  end
```

Which I use like this:

```
  Messaging::Publisher.publish(event: {... event details...})
```

Then I have my 'listener':

```
  # app/agents/messaging/events_queue_receiver.rb
  require_dependency "#{Rails.root.join('app','agents','messaging','events_agent')}"

  module Messaging
    class EventsQueueReceiver
      include Sneakers::Worker
      from_queue :events_queue, env: nil

      def work(msg)
        logger.info msg
        response = Messaging::EventsAgent.distribute(JSON.parse(msg).with_indifferent_access)
        ack! if response[:success]
      end

    end
  end
```

The 'listener' sends the message to `Messaging::EventsAgent.distribute`, which is like this:

```
  # app/agents/messaging/events_agent.rb
 require_dependency  #{Rails.root.join('app','agents','fsm','state_assignment_agent')}"

  module Messaging
    class EventsAgent
      EVENT_HANDLERS = {
        enroll_in_program: ["FSM::StateAssignmentAgent"]
      }
      class << self

        def publish(event)
          Messaging::Publisher.publish(event: event)
        end

        def distribute(event)
          puts "in #{self}.#{__method__}, message"
          if event[:handler]
            puts "in #{self}.#{__method__}, event[:handler: #{event[:handler}"
            event[:handler].constantize.handle_event(event)
          else
            event_name = event[:event_name].to_sym
            EVENT_HANDLERS[event_name].each do |handler|
              event[:handler] = handler
              publish(event)
            end
          end
          return {success: true}
        end

      end
    end
  end
```

Following the instructions on Codetunes, I have:

```
  # Rakefile
  # Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
  # for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

  require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

  require 'sneakers/tasks'
  Rails.application.load_tasks
```

And:

```
  # app/config/sneakers.rb
  Sneakers.configure({})
  Sneakers.logger.level = Logger::INFO # the default DEBUG is too noisy
```

I open two console windows. In the first, I say (to get my listener running):

```
  $ WORKERS=Messaging::EventsQueueReceiver rake sneakers:run
  ... a bunch of start up info
  2016-03-18T14:16:42Z p-5877 t-14d03e INFO: Heartbeat interval used (in seconds): 2
  2016-03-18T14:16:42Z p-5899 t-14d03e INFO: Heartbeat interval used (in seconds): 2
  2016-03-18T14:16:42Z p-5922 t-14d03e INFO: Heartbeat interval used (in seconds): 2
  2016-03-18T14:16:42Z p-5944 t-14d03e INFO: Heartbeat interval used (in seconds): 2
```

In the second, I say:

```
  $ rails s --sandbox
  2.1.2 :001 > Messaging::Publisher.publish({:event=>{:event_name=>"enroll_in_program", :program_system_name=>"aha_chh", :person_id=>1}})
  in Messaging::Publisher.publish, [x] Sent {:event=>{:event_name=>"enroll_in_program", :program_system_name=>"aha_chh", :person_id=>1}}!
  => :closed
```

Then, back in my first window, I see:

```
  2016-03-18T14:17:44Z p-5877 t-19nfxy INFO: {"event_name":"enroll_in_program","program_system_name":"aha_chh","person_id":1}
  in Messaging::EventsAgent.distribute, message
  in Messaging::EventsAgent.distribute, event[:handler]: FSM::StateAssignmentAgent
```

And in my RabbitMQ server, I see:

[image]

It's a pretty minimal setup and I'm sure I'll be learning a lot more in coming days.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that for RabbitMQ at least you will need a client. RabbitMQ implements the AMQP protocol, as opposed to the HTTP protocol used by web servers. As Sergio mentioned above, Rails is a web framework, so it doesn't have AMQP support built into it. You'll have to use an AMQP client such as Bunny in order to subscribe to a Rabbit queue from within a Rails app.

Comment: Sure - I was aware that there needs to be some piece of software between RabbitMQ and Rails. But my understanding/hope is that this client can be called / can life within the Rails app!? If so, how would I "trigger" the subscribe process? (And then also: how to process the events so that I can process them in the rails context of my app?)

Comment: A RabbitMQ client can be used within a Rails app. You can have Rails run a background task that will maintain the queue subscription and process incoming messages.

Based on what you've told me, it sounds like the [sneakers](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers) library is probably a better option for you than Bunny. It's meant for situations where queue processing happens in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say Service A is sending some events to Kafka queue, you can have a background process running with your Rails app which would lookup into the kafka queue and process those queued messages. For background process you can go for cron-job or sidekiq kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is a lot of things. Parts of it handle web requests. Other parts (ActiveRecord) don't care if you are a web request or a script or whatever. Rails itself does not even come with a production worthy web server, you use other gems (e.g., `thin` for plain old web browsers, or `wash_out` for incoming SOAP requests) for that. Rails only gives you the infrastructure/middleware to combine all the pieces regarding servers.

Unless your queue can call out to your application in some fashion of HTTP, for example in the form of SOAP requests, you'll need something that listens to your queueing system, whatever that may be, and translates new "tickets" on your queue into controller actions in your Rails world.